# For loop in r for if else statements

Tags: r, as.date

[image]Good morning,
I can't quite grasp what I am doing wrong here, could someone assist? I am trying to convert my datetime in r but some of my dates are "Jan." or "Aug." so I get null values when I try to convert it to date/time.

My solution is to separate by delimiter, grab the month, rename the month, put the date back together, and then go from there. I can't figure out the loop though and keep getting "July".

My dataframe is separated now into July 14 2022 (df$left, df$middle, df$right)

```r
for (month in df$left){
    if (df$left == "July")
    {df$month <- "July"}
    else if (df$left == "Aug.")
    {df$month <- "August"
    if (df$left == "Sept.")
    {df$month <- "September"}
    if (df$left == "Oct.")
    {df$month <- "October"}
    if (df$left == "Nov.")
    {df$month <- "November"}
    if (df$left == "Dec.")
    {df$month <- "Dec."}
    if (df$left == "Jan.")
    {df$month <- "January"}
    if (df$left == "Feb.")
    {df$month <- "February"}
    if (df$left == "March")
    {df$month <- "March"}
    if (df$left == "April")
    {df$month <- "April"}
    if (df$left == "May")
    {df$month <- "May"}
    if (df$left == "June")
    {df$month <- "June"}
    if (df$left == "July")
    {df$month <- "July"}
    if (df$left == "Aug.")
    {df$month <- "August"}
}
```

```
left    middle  right   Workout.Date    Activity.Type
<chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
1   July    14, 2022    July 14, 2022   Run
```

Comment: Can you share a small sample of your data? `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  That said, R is vectorised by default, so you shouldn't need to use a loop.  Moreover, you should be able to do what you want in a single line, without separating and restitching your dates.  Something like `df$myDate <- stringr::str_replace(df$myDate, fixed("."), "")`.  The `fixed` is needed because `str_repace` uses regexes by default.

Comment: @TomHoel I tried to attach a photo but it added a link, that is the df.

Comment: Question updated with an example of the dataframe. It continues further with calories burned, time, pace, etc. It is just a mapmyrun dataset I use for fun and learning.

Comment: *I am trying to convert my datetime* ... Please show trial not just your attempted solution. Even then, show how you split the date field. You still can convert with those abbreviations.

Comment: df$Workout.Date <- as.Date(df$Workout.Date, format = "%B %e, %Y")
df$Date.Submitted <- as.Date(df$Date.Submitted, format = "%B %e, %Y")

Comment: My problem is any of the months that are abbreviated come out as NA (Aug., Jan. etc)

Comment: FYI, in stackoverflow code formatting, code blocks can be determined by using code fences as you've done, but the fences `\`\`\`` _must be on their own lines_, i.e., there must not be code on the same line. One consequence is that the first line of code (that is on the same line as the first backticks) is not visible in the rendered page. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lubridate backage is fairly clever at working out how to interpret a date.  I'm using the tidyverse simply for formatting and showing the column type easily.

First, create some test data

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(Workout.Date=c("July 14, 2022", "Jul. 14, 2022", 
                           "September 1, 2021", "Sept. 1, 2021"))
```

Now, a one line solution:

```
d %>% mutate(Workout.Date=mdy(Workout.Date))
  Workout.Date
  <date>      
1 2022-07-14  
2 2022-07-14  
3 2021-09-01  
4 2021-09-01
```

Comment: Perfect! You saved a lot of work!  I am used to using python in jupyter, for r do you need to load the library in each cell when using a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to perform a couple of passes to fully convert all of the entries.
Convert all of the dates with the full month name, then for the rows which returned NA attempt to convert those with a different format string.

Here is an example using base R

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" Workout.Date 
'Jul. 14, 2022'
'July 15, 2022'
'Jul. 16, 2022'
'Jul. 17, 2022'
'Jul  18, 2022'
'July 19, 2022'
'July 20, 2022'
'July 21, 2022'
'July 22, 2022'")


df$date <- as.Date(df$Workout.Date, format = "%B %e, %Y")
#now try a different format on the rows with NA
#abbreviated followed by .
df$date[is.na(df$date)] <- as.Date(df$Workout.Date[is.na(df$date)], format = "%b. %e, %Y")
#abbreviated no .
df$date[is.na(df$date)] <- as.Date(df$Workout.Date[is.na(df$date)], format = "%b %e, %Y")
```